# Appointment vs. meeting (vs. date)

Tags: word-choice, meaning

What is the difference in meaning between these words?

I would use *date* if I were single, I like a woman, and I want to spend some time with her; let's say that this word is different from the other two at least for me.

A meeting is an event where many people meet, and I may attend the meeting of the National Society for Advancement of Sleep Techniques, say. But if I will participate to a series of events and I have to write them down with a title, should I say *Next appointments* or *Next meetings*?

Comment: The word "date" has also been used in such phrases as "date with destiny", which in turn has been used as the title of at least one book and who knows how many TV episodes.

Comment: ...which in Italian would be translated as "**appuntamento** col destino**" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An appointment is a formal arrangement to meet or visit somebody. To me, that means you and somebody else took a decision about when to meet; for example, that would be the case for a dental appointment.
In your case, I would use *next meetings*.

As side note, in British English *date* also means "an arrangement to meet somebody at a particular time"; in all the English dialects, *date* also means "romantic meeting."

Comment: thanks, I knew only of the second meaning of "date" (besides of course "today's date is April 3")